# How to refactor and make these if statements better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, refactoring

I have a ton of `if` statements that I am tasked to refactor and make more readable.

The `if` statements rely on 2/3 JSON keys and I cannot think of a good way to make it better.

Does anyone have any tips for me?

These `if` statements were nested inside some other `if` statements, but I used a rules engine to help break it down. But I feel like a rules engine might not break this down to a better solution.

I’m thinking something like a map or lookup table, but I can’t process how to do this.

```js
if (LM <= 15) {
  if (COMWT <= 25000) {
    COST = 225.0;
  }
  
  if (COMWT > 25000) {
    if (COMWT <= 30000) {
      COST = 275.0;
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 15) {
  if (LM <= 25) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 250;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 300.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 25) {
  if (LM <= 40) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 275;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 325.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 40) {
  if (LM <= 55) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 325;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 350.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 55) {
  if (LM <= 70) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 375;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 400.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 70) {
  if (LM <= 85) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 425;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 450.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 85) {
  if (LM <= 100) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 475;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 500.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 100) {
  if (LM <= 125) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 525;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 550.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 125) {
  if (LM <= 150) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = 575;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = 600.0;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 150) {
  if (LM <= 300) {
    if (COMWT <= 25000) {
      COST = LM * 3;
    }
    
    if (COMWT > 25000) {
      if (COMWT <= 30000) {
        COST = LM * 3.5;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (LM > 300) {
  if (COMWT <= 25000) {
    COST = LM * 2.5;
  }
  
  if (COMWT > 25000) {
    if (COMWT <= 30000) {
      COST = LM * 3;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're asking for us to review your code, please consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Have you considered using the `else` keyword? Also, `if(A){ if(B){`…`} }` can be rewritten as `if(A && B){`…`}`.

Comment: Oh no this isn't my code. I was given this code to try and refactor/make better, but Im struggling to get started. There are about 3000 more lines of code with this near same logic, so I am trying to build a great process to handle this same logic without it being nested ifs over and over

Comment: @SebastianSimon agreed. The person that originally wrote this used absolute 0 else's.....

Comment: Man when LM is greater than 300 it goes into every if statement before that

Comment: @epascarello yeah, its bad.

Comment: Ouch. Usually when I see stuff like this, I work from the inside out. Here, combine the unnecessarily nested `if` conditions, then consider where `else`s can be placed. Structured coding is key.

Comment: What happens if COMWT > 30000?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks. I didn't know that page existed.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thats a good perspective, that might help some.

Comment: @James nothing.. it just falls through.

Answer (score 1):

Store the checks in a variable and start with the greatest and work your way down to the lowest

```
const comwtLow = COMWT <= 25000;
const comwtHigh = COMWT > 25000 && COMWT <= 30000

let COST;

if (LM > 300 && comwtLow) COST = LM * 2.5;
else if (LM > 300 && comwtHigh) COST = LM * 3;
else if (LM > 150 && comwtLow) COST = LM * 3;
else if (LM > 150 && comwtHigh) COST = LM * 3.5;
else if (LM > 125 && comwtLow) COST = 575;
else if (LM > 125 && comwtHigh) COST = 600;
....
```

Without if/else you can do a data structure with an object and store the base part of the fees. Use a loop to find the fee structure that matches and generate the cost.

```js
const fees = {
  300: {
    low: { multi: 2.5 },
    high: { multi: 3 },
  },
  150: {
    low: { multi: 3 },
    high: { multi: 3.5 },
  },
  125: {
    low: { flat: 575 },
    high: { flat: 600 },
  },
  0: {
    low: { flat: 225 },
    high: { flat: 275 },
  },
}

const feesValues = Object.keys(fees).map(Number).sort((a,b)=>b-a);

function getCost (lm, comwt) {
  const range = comwt <= 25000 ? "low" : "high";
  const feeData = fees[feesValues.find(value => value < lm)];
  const { multi = 0, flat = 0 } = feeData[range];
  return lm * multi + flat;
}

console.log(getCost(400, 10000));
console.log(getCost(130, 10000));
```

This code expects there to be matches on everything. If that is not the case, you need to add more logic and protection around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by storing it into an array of objects.

```
Note: Please verify all conditions before using this code
```

```js
const conditionList = [
    {
        high: 15,
        low: 0,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 225
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 275
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 25,
        low: 15,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 250
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 300
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 40,
        low: 25,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 275
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 325
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 55,
        low: 40,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 325
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 350
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 70,
        low: 55,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 375
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 400
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 85,
        low: 70,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 425
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 450
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 100,
        low: 85,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 475
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 500
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 125,
        low: 100,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 525
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 550
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 150,
        low: 125,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => 575
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => 600
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        high: 300,
        low: 150,
        comwt: [
            {
                high: 25000,
                low: 0,
                cost: lm => lm * 3
            },
            {
                high: 30000,
                low: 25000,
                cost: lm => lm * 3.5
            }
        ]
    }
];


function cal(lm, cmwt) {
    let costd = 0;
    conditionList.forEach(item => {
        if (lm >= item.low && lm <= item.high) {
            item.comwt.forEach(c => {
                if (cmwt >= c.low && cmwt <= c.high) {
                    costd = c.cost(lm);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return costd;
}

console.log(cal(75, 24000));
```